# time zone issue with MyBatis + MyBatis CDI + PostgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, mybatis, ibatis, mybatis-cdi

I have a strange time-zone issue in MyBatis.

**Environment:**

- mybatis v3.4.5
- mybatis-cdi v1.0.1
- Payara app Server v4.1.2.173
- PostgreSQL database
- JNDI datasource, MANAGED transaction setting

**At first** I am inserting a record into a table where there is a date-time field.
On Java side it is a `java.time.ZonedDateTime`. In the database I use `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` for this field.

This is the relevant piece of code:

```
request.setRequestDate = ZonedDateTime.now();
LOGGER.info("xxx-xxx-xxx: " + httpRequest.getRequestDate());
myMapper.save(request);
```

In the logfile I can see this:

```
[INFO ] 2017-10-18 18:43:45,501 com..................... - xxx-xxx-xxx: 2017-10-18T18:43:45.493+02:00[Europe/Prague]
[DEBUG] 2017-10-18 18:43:45,608 com...xxxDao.saveRequest - ==>  Preparing: INSERT INTO table_a (id, ..., request_date) VALUES (?, ?, ...) 
[DEBUG] 2017-10-18 18:43:45,770 com...xxxDao.saveRequest - ==> Parameters: 281(Long), ..., 2017-10-18 16:43:45.493(Timestamp)
[DEBUG] 2017-10-18 18:43:45,783 com...xxxDao.saveRequest - <==    Updates: 1
```

In the database this is the result:

```
select request_date from table_a
result: 2017-10-18 16:43:45.493
```

That is okay because I use GMT time zone in the database.

**Then** I am executing another sql insert on the same datasource with different mapper class (the POJO is different ass well), but the Java and SQL types are same. The issue is that the date-time value is inserted with `GMT+2` timezone into the database instead of `GMT`:

```
[INFO ] 2017-10-18 18:43:46,188 com..................... - yyy-yyy-yyy: 2017-10-18T18:43:46.188+02:00[Europe/Prague]
[DEBUG] 2017-10-18 18:43:46,190 com...yyyDao.saveMetadata - ==>  Preparing: INSERT INTO table_b (id,..., uploaded) VALUES (?, ?, ...) 
[DEBUG] 2017-10-18 18:43:46,202 com...yyyDao.saveMetadata - ==> Parameters: 561(Long), ..., 2017-10-18 18:43:46.188(Timestamp)
[DEBUG] 2017-10-18 18:43:46,212 com...yyyDao.saveMetadata - <==    Updates: 1
```

As you can see the value is inserted with wrong time-zone:

```
select uploaded from table_b
result: 2017-10-18 18:43:46.188
```

My first guess was it comes from the wrong database pool settings so I have added the following property to my pool configuration:

```
sessionTimeZone=UTC
```

But I am still inserting the 1st date-time in UTC and the 2nd in UTC+2 time-zone.

I have tried to log out the details of the java.sql.Connection to see what a hell is going here so I injected SqlSqssion into my code (@Inject SqlSession sqlSession) but of course I got a `org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionException: Error:  Cannot get connection.  No managed session is started..` exception because I use MANAGED transaction handling.

Any idea what to check?

**----- UPDATE 1 -----**

So I changed everything to UTC as per the suggestion:

- postgresql.conf: timezone = 'UTC'
- app server: -Duser.timezone=UTC

It seems okay, BUT...

When I execute my query in PostgreSQL console this is the result:

```
demo=# select EXTRACT(TIMEZONE FROM uploaded), uploaded from image_metadata;
 date_part |          uploaded
-----------+----------------------------
         0 | 2017-10-25 00:24:11.873+00
(1 row)
```

Same query result in SqurielSQL:

```
date_part   uploaded
0           2017-10-25 02:24:11.873
```

It seems that my SQL client does some tricky timezone conversation at the background but I am not sure. I need to check it.

**----- UPDATE 2 -----**

I am not sure what was the problem but my issue was solved after I have changed the database and JVM timezone setting to UTC.

I use the following SQL query to get back the stored date-time value from database:

```
SELECT current_timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'
```

Comment: yep, every client (including java) will use local system timezone by default, unless another value is explicitly specified either as an option in connection url (depending on db vendor) or by command such as [set session timezone] (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-set.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would set everything at UTC to make everything simpler.

```
LOGGER.info(TimeZone.getDefault().getID())
```

If it displays anything else than UTC, then add VM argument `-Duser.timezone=UTC` to the application startup.

There is a confusion in the snippet variables `request` / `httpRequest`, maybe just a typo ?

> **request**.setRequestDate = ZonedDateTime.now();
>
> LOGGER.info("xxx-xxx-xxx: " + **httpRequest**.getRequestDate());

Comment: That was just a typo, sorry for that. It seems my SQL client does something unexpected. Please check the update info in the post.